I'm going to use my personal laptop as a server, however I need a dualboot
So I decided to make my own server using my own personal laptop, however I need it to dualboot any linux distro alongside the server. Basically that I have two options at startup, either whatever ubuntu distro, and the proxmox server. I may need help from anyone who has done this, as no-one probably did on youtube.
Edit: The question is, i'm wondering if it's possible or not, and how would I do it?

What is the question?

Here is how to install ubuntu server https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server

@ArchismanPanigrahi Sorry, clarified it more in the post.

But can I still dualboot..?

Of course. You can dual boot while installation of the new distro

To answer the first question yes you can dualboot; The second is a bit more complicated most distros have dualboot guides and you can search it up but for  most graphical distros eg. ubuntu, linux mint, fedora etc in the setup when it asks you how you partition the disk you select "install this alongside" option and it should autopartition your drive to where its the grub dualboot screen appears.
